# Cron makes user as public in permission

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, chmod

**Setting:**

I am running a wordpress site with a custom cron job using `crontab -e`.

In my php file, I have the following to execute a function:

```
require('/var/www/html/wp-load.php');
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

if (!empty($argv[1])) {        
    switch ($argv[1]){
        case 'init':
            chmod_or_mkdir_function();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

If I run this function (`chmod_or_mkdir_function()`) through normal wp route (not through cronjob), it works just fine. 
However when I run it through cronjob, I get `chmod(): Operation not permitted in` or `folder is not writable` error.

The permission is already set to `775` and they only work when I change to `777`, which I really don't want to for a security reason.

**My guess:**

My guess is that when I call my php file through a cronjob, I am somehow not viewed as `admin` nor `group` but as `public`.

How would I go about to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically Wordpress runs under the webserver's user, such as apache, whereas you are you. You can change the group the file belongs to to one that you and Wordpress are both members of. Since the file is already group-writeable (775), changing its group to one you're both members of should do the trick. You can use the chgrp command:

`chgrp newgroup file`

If your file is actually a directory, throw in -R to make it recursive:

`chgrp -R newgroup file`

Comment: That makes total sense! I will give it try for sure! Thanks. 